# K Map, Essential prime Implicant

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

[image]

I have solved  the above problem in two ways.And both the times I have a unique solution with the same number of gates.

According to my understanding of Essential Prime Implicants, This particular case does not contain any essential prime implicants, as two ways of solution is possible.Is my interpretation correct?

But is it possible to have a solution without EPI's?
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A solution, or the *optimal* solution?

Comment: Yes, Optimal solution.

Comment: how about not( ( P xor Q ) xor R )?

Comment: I don't think you've got it right.  For every cluster of ones in a Karnaugh map, there's ALWAYS another way to do it.  If no other way, you can always just express each 1 individually.

Comment: Is it possible then to have Q'S' as EPI in the first case and QS as EPI in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

Some maps do not have Essential Prime Implicants.  However, if they are present they should always be included in the solution.  Once all EPIs have been used, then you must choose enough Prime Implicants to "Cover" the function.  Covering means to use all 1s or 0s, depending on SOP or POS, that are present in the map.

Comment: So will the above case, one without EPI or different EPI's depending on the grouping!